# Genymotion Error: Error, unable to start VirtualBox on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: android, ubuntu, virtualbox, genymotion

I'm trying to start Genymotion in Ubuntu 16.10. I have installed both genymotion and virtual box on terminal. I use Ubuntu 16.10 but barely newby on linux. Genymotion give this error:

> Error, unable to start genymotion and Genymotion requires VirtualBox
>   to be installed.

[image: genymotion error]

I already installed VirtualBox on PC,some websites say solution is in virtualbox preferences and network problems but host only networks is empty.
[image: virtualbox]
Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use the answer section to provide the answer for your problem and it would also be more readable if you would remove the answer part from your question (even the 'SOLVED' in your title is not really needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BIOS secure mode disabled. The problem solved after that.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please? Where did you set that configuration?